# Terraform dependency on template

Tags: terraform

I have a template file that is used to create a config file that is then used to help provision an instance.

If the template file changes I want "terraform apply" to trigger the regeneration of the config file and then when the config file changes I want that to trigger the regeneration of the instance.

Is there a way to do this with terraform?

```
data "template_file" "instance_config" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/instance_config.tpl")}"
  vars {
    private_cidr_block = "${var.private_cidr_block}"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "export_instance_config" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "cat >instance_config.json <<EOL\n${data.template_file.instance_config.rendered}\nEOL"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "vpn" {
  ami           = "${data.aws_ami.my_ami.id}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "mykey"
  subnet_id = "${var.subnet_id}"
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.instance_sg.id}"]

  connection {
    type = "ssh"
    user = "myuser"
    private_key = "${file("mykey.pem")}"
    agent = false
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    source = "instance_config.json"
    destination = "/home/myuser/instance_config.json"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo /usr/bin/configure_instance /home/myuser/instance_config.json"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce complexity and fix the dependency chain by utilizing the feature of provisioners outlined [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/file.html#content).

Specifically, I think you can remove the `null_resource` provisioner and instead do the following:

```
data "template_file" "instance_config" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/instance_config.tpl")}"

  vars {
    private_cidr_block = "${var.private_cidr_block}"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "vpn" {
  ami           = "${data.aws_ami.my_ami.id}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name      = "mykey"
  subnet_id     = "${var.subnet_id}"

  associate_public_ip_address = true

  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.instance_sg.id}"]

  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "myuser"
    private_key = "${file("mykey.pem")}"
    agent       = false
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    content     = "${data.template_file.instance_config.rendered}"
    destination = "/home/myuser/instance_config.json"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo /usr/bin/configure_instance /home/myuser/instance_config.json"
    ]
  }
}
```